# Google Api Client give null onConnected method and getting LastLocation also null

Tags: android, android-googleapiclient

Google client implementation is given below:

```
   if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                        .addConnectionCallbacks((GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener((GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) this)
                        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                        .build();
            }
```

onStart i am connecting GoogleApiClient

```
  @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

till here everything is fine but on connected method its return null

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    if (bundle != null)// always null
        Log.e(TAG, bundle.toString());
}
```

Getting code for location on onClick of floating button after connected to google api client

```
 //Floating Action Button
            floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                                            //To Check Runtime Permission
                                                            checkRuntimePermission();
                                                            mMap.clear();
                                                            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                                                            mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
                                                            mLocationRequest.setInterval(50);
                                                            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10);
                                                            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);


                                                            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

                                                            if (!Utils.GPS_SERVICE(mContext)) {
                                                                Utils.isGPSOnline(mContext);
                                                            }

                                                            if (mLastLocation != null) {
                                                                double lon = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
                                                                double lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                                                                LatLng latlng = new LatLng(lat, lon);
                                                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title("My_location"));

                                                                //TO move the marker when user enter any Location
                                                                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
                                                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
```

Comment: what do you want in Bundle?

Comment: also post your full code and i want to see where u initiate the google api client

Comment: @phanVanLinh i want to know that i have connected to the client or not

Comment: @quicklearner i have posted already

Comment: @NikhilSharma if the callback return to `onConnected` that mean GoogleApiClient is connected (bundle = null or != null is not important). if it is not connect, callback will return to `onConnectionFailed`

Comment: @phan Van Linh yeah your right but even thn my last location is null and earlier this code working fine suddenly i dont knw what hppn

Comment: @NikhilSharma when/where do you call `getLastLocation`, make sure you get it after GoogleApiClient is connected

Comment: @phan Van linh after my maps get loaded after that onButtonClick event i am requesting for my location\

Comment: @NikhilSharma are you sure at this time, GoogleApiClient is connected?

Answer (score 0):

If `onConnected()` getting called, you `GoogleApiClient` is okay.

> Why bundle is null?

Have a look at this method -

```
public abstract void onConnected (Bundle connectionHint)
```

**Contents of the `connectionHint` Bundle are defined by the specific services.  *May be null if no content is provided by the service*.**

Comment: Thanks but still the same this happing :(

Comment: @NikhilSharma returning bundle should not be a problem because it is being managed bu Google play services. Look at the edited answer.

Comment: yeah your right my GoogleApiClient its ok but onConnected retruning null as well as my LastLocation always null

Comment: Wrap whole code of `onClick()` with `if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())` and check if client is null or what? Further make sure runtime permissions are granted as well.

Comment: Yeah i have debug it m Googleclient is connected and permissions also granted but using android 4.4 version

Comment: Thanks for your help but now everything is working fine i dont knw what this happing

Comment: I have the same problem, I'm getting null connectionHint, what is the solution for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks((GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener((GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
.enableAutoManage(activityContext, this) // this - for implementing Interface
                    .build();
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "activityContext"

Comment: If your activity is MainActivity then context would be `MainActivity.this`

Comment: this is not working also and earlier everything working fine but suddenly its not working

Comment: you should debug it in every callback

Answer (score 0):

Remove this condition as well `if (mGoogleApiClient == null)` and pass this in callbacks

```
                mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                        .build();
```

You can Look this also for complete example
http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/

Comment: this is not working but can you explain me why i should remove if condition

Comment: ooh but he is using synchronized

Comment: but there no problem with GoogleApiClient its initialing properly

Comment: check the value of mGoogleApiClient in every callback and if its null initialize it again

Comment: Its work my code was fine only problem with permission of GPS which i have disagreed so everythng working fine thanks1